# Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'CountdownTimerModule' was called

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build production files, however `aot` is failing with this error message:

`Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'CountdownTimerModule' was called.`

I am building with `npm run build -- --prod --aot` and then this issue hits.

When i look at the compenent in question, I have it setup as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ThemeModule,
    CountdownTimerModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    Component
  ],
  providers: [Service]
})
```

How do I get around this declaration error and use the countdown timer module?

Comment: Why are you declaring CountdownTimerModule inside declarations array?

Comment: Sorry that was an error, I have removed it from the post.

Comment: Can you show your `CountdownTimerModule`?

Comment: I resolved this issue by swapping to this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular8-countdown-timer

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by swapping to this module: npmjs.com/package/angular8-countdown-timer